# Why GCP loadbalancer frontend has only two ports enabled?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create a load balancer in GCP. I have created two instance groups and each instance group has single vm attached to itself. One vm is having a port 80 and another vm is having a port enabled at 86.

The moment I create a load balancer, I find a frontend ip configuration always enabled at 80.

I am looking forward to something like this, ip:80 and ip:86. Since I am new to GCP, I am struggling with this part

Comment: The port number for the frontend is not related to the backend port number. Why do you want to configure port 80 and port 86 for the frontend?

Comment: The HTTPS load balancer has 2 port in HTTP (80 and 8080) and 1 in HTTPS (443). If you want other ports, you can use TCP load balancer.

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere I created Tcp load balancer but it has only one health check available. if health check 80 is enabled then 86 port does not work.

Comment: John Hanley, I am making a load balancer which is port based. one port is for vm1 and second port is for vm2. I need one single ip and it should redirect to VMS based on ports. In azure and AWS I used the same concept but not sure how will i manage it in GCP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [forwarding rule](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/forwarding-rule-concepts#port_specifications) and its corresponding IP address represent the frontend configuration of a Google Cloud load balancer. With Google cloud you can create a single forwarding rule with a single IP by adding 2 ports separated by comma.
This port limitation for the [TCP proxy load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tcp/setting-up-tcp#console) and is due to the way TCP proxy load balancers are managed within the GCP internal infrastructure. It is not possible to use any port outside of this list.

For example:
Create a named port for the instance group.

gcloud compute instance-groups set-named-ports us-ig2 
--named-ports tcp110:110 
--zone us-east1-b

gcloud compute health-checks create tcp my-tcp-health-check --port 110